# Performance Improvement for Bulk Processing in cx_Oracle

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, performance-testing, bulkinsert, cx-oracle

Facing Performance issue while bulk loading the data into oracle using cx_Oracle. it seems the append hint doesn't work with cx_Oracle or atleast i'm not able to make it work. any help will be greatly appreciated

I was trying to push 2 million records in a batch to Oracle using cx_Oracle , but it is taking 1.5 min while from oracle to oracle if i use append hint its taking 20 sec only.

```
insertquery="""insert /*+ append parallel(XYZ,8) */ into XYZ(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S)             VALUES('abc',:B,'N',:D,:E,:F,:G,:H,:I,:J,:K,:L,:M,:N,:O,'MIG','MIG',{current_time},{current_time})""".format(current_time=current_time)


print("XYZ START",datetime.datetime.now())
trg_cur.prepare(insertquery)
trg_cur.executemany(None,entityList)'''
```

time taken remains unchanged if i keep the append hint or not. is there any way to improve this performance other than threads , i would be running this in multiple threads as my input data can range to few hundred millions rows and i have to insert this data in multiple table

Answer (score 0):

using append_Values worked like a charm and 40 sec reduced to 10 sec for pushing 1 million records

```
insertquery="""insert /*+ append_values parallel(XYZ,8) */ into XYZ(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S)             VALUES('abc',:B,'N',:D,:E,:F,:G,:H,:I,:J,:K,:L,:M,:N,:O,'MIG','MIG',{current_time},{current_time})""".format(current_time=current_time)
```